# Entity Framework Return List from Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I'm trying to return a list of int from a stored procedure in Entity Framework.

I created the stored procedure fine, and added it into Entity Framework. I'm trying to bind it to a complex type of but when I open the function import.

It auto generates a complex type that only returns an int instead of a results set.

Does anyone know how I can import an entity that returns a list as a result set?

Comment: Show us some code you already have so we can help.

Comment: This isn't really code related. I can added an empty class with a list of ints in there but this is GUI Related,  I'm not using code-first, so It should be all through the GUI.

Comment: I have a Stored procedure that basically just selects a list of ids I want to grab that in c#

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I created this sample stored procedure returning a list of int values:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetListOfInt
AS BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM 
    (VALUES (42), (4711), (8088), (80286), (80486), (655235)) AS VT(VC)
END
```

I then added this stored procedure to my EF `.edmx` model and created this Function Import:

[image]

Querying the stored procedure shows me that it returns a result set consisting of `int` values - I therefore define the return value to be *a collection of Scalar: Int32* in the function import dialog.

After that, I can call that stored procedure and get back the results like this:

```
using (testEntities ctx = new testEntities())
{
    ObjectResult<int?> result = ctx.GetListOfInt();

    foreach (int intValue in result.AsEnumerable())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("INT value returned: {0}", intValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're still around do you happen to know why, it initially returns a nullable results set, when in step two you can see that nullable is false

Comment: @Space: I was wondering that myself - not sure, sorry. I guess EF just cannot be *sure* that at least one row is returned - the stored procedure (if it were a bit more realistic) might also just return nothing at all (if there's no matching rows in the table for the `WHERE` criteria supplied)

Comment: This worked, but casting was required when returning the List back to API call. So whoever is implementing this don't forget to cast properly if facing errors.

Comment: Actually, that doesn't make sense. If it didn't return any rows, the result would be an empty list, not a list of empty elements. Stupid and still a mystery after all these years.

Answer (score 25):

If your just trying to get a list from a stored procedure you don't need to map anything special.

Just Call it Like this:

```
var results = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<int>("SP_YourSP").ToList();
```

this should return a list of ints

Comment: This worked for me. It's an exception to the object mapping, but gets the work done without extra headache

Comment: @AntoinePelletier What does MVC and WebForms have to do with what technology your are using to access your database?

Comment: I used this technique in both `MVC` and `web-form` with the EXACT SAME version of entity framework, it was ok in `MVC` but it did not work in `web-form`. To begin with, there is no `.Database` in web form, the function does not exist. Maybe it's just me, did you succeded with this in `web-form` ?

Comment: I’ve edited my answer to be a bit more clear. The database is a property on your dbContext for EF.  If your using the same version of EF there should always be a database property on your context.

Comment: But then again, the question does not mention inside which technologie entity was used, so it's still a valid answer, I just realized it...

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that it could lead to a runtime error further down the line if the stored proc changed name or was removed. Having the stored proc properly mapped will cause a compile-time error if if were to be removed

Comment: @AdamHey If someone deletes your sp, will receive a runtime error in both cases, unless you regenerate your model

Comment: @johnny5 - that's precisely my point. You open your code up to errors that may only manifest at runtime, not compile time. With the above approach, regenerating the model from the DB will have no effect. It's executing sql against the db, not using the model

Comment: @AdamHey,  I get your point, but it shouldn't but too much to worry about, Regenerating the model generally not a step part of the build, So you have the same risk of deploying with runtime errors in both cases.  You will that as a compiler error, if you're modifying the DB Model, which in active products doesn't happen that often.    If someone is delete Stored Procedures on your SQL Server, you have more issues than just runtime errors

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get a list with a mapped class, try this

```
var results = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<youclass>("SP_YourSP").ToList();
```