# How to get exec(query) result from stored procedure in webform using entity framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, webforms

Stored procedure return result in the form of `EXEC(@strSQL_1)`.

and I access it from my code by

```
var FilterList = storeDb.COMPLETE_PREFIX_PAGING(pageIndex, pageSize, operatorId, categoryId, countryIds); //storedb.NNPCs.ToList();
```

but the result return in the form of `int`, not in the form of list or table.
what I do for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the Stored Procedure returning result in the mapping you created in the model.

See below example

[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29012920/entity-framework-return-list-from-stored-procedure)

Comment: I am not understanding what are happening in it.

Comment: Follow the sample and modify the mapping to let the procedure return your collection