# SQL Stored procedure returning -1 from C# Code but returning values when executed directly

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have a stored procedure :-

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Usp_GetFilterDM]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @shortid nvarchar(10),
    @dmno nvarchar(10),
    @LOB int,
    @Status int
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @sqlCommand nvarchar(1000)

SET @sqlCommand ='SELECT *  FROM [ProjectTracker].[dbo].[View_GetALLDM] where (status <> 1 and status <> 2) '

IF @shortid <>'NO'
 SET @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + 'and shortid  LIKE ''%'+ @shortid +'%'''

IF @dmno <>'NO'
 SET @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + 'and DMNO LIKE ''%'+@dmno+'%'''

IF @LOB<> -1
 SET @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + 'and LOB = @LOB '

 IF @Status <> -1
 SET @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + 'and Status = @Status' 


EXEC sp_executesql @sqlCommand, N' @LOB INT,@Status int',  @LOB,@Status; 




END
```

When i execute it directly i get the values, but when i use it in my C# code using ado .net model and call it like this :-

```
var x = obj.Usp_GetFilterDM(shortid,dmno,LOB,status);
            var userDataString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x);
            return userDataString;
```

I get output as -1 for all the cases, i have used stored procedure for all my queries and it all works but this is the first time that i have used dynamic build query and sp_executeSQL. Generally i would just write a select query and it always works.

Code Under USP_GetFilterDM:-

```
 public virtual int Usp_GetFilterDM(string shortid, string dmno, Nullable<int> lOB, Nullable<int> status)
        {
            var shortidParameter = shortid != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("shortid", shortid) :
                new ObjectParameter("shortid", typeof(string));

            var dmnoParameter = dmno != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("dmno", dmno) :
                new ObjectParameter("dmno", typeof(string));

            var lOBParameter = lOB.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("LOB", lOB) :
                new ObjectParameter("LOB", typeof(int));

            var statusParameter = status.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("Status", status) :
                new ObjectParameter("Status", typeof(int));

            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("Usp_GetFilterDM", shortidParameter, dmnoParameter, lOBParameter, statusParameter);
        }
```

Comment: Show us the code inside `Usp_GetFilterDM` in C#

Comment: [Entity Framework Return List from Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29012920/entity-framework-return-list-from-stored-procedure) shows a screenshot of how a stored proc is mapped. Can you show the same for yours?

Comment: Do you know which sql command was being used?  The command would have the option to use stored procedure as well as the string query.  There are four commands : Select, Insert, Update, and Delete.

Comment: I have dynamically build a select query which pulls data from A view and then for filter i am building sql query dynamically