Generate DTO models dynamically based on the data returned by the stored procedure
I have a scenario where I am passing table name as parameter to SQL Server stored procedure and it returns the data from that table.
The data structure that stored procedure returns varies based on the parameter (table name) that I am passing to it.
In my existing implementation where the data structure is fixed, i.e the columns returned by the stored procedure do no change, we are using predefined DTOs which looks like this:
public IList<UserDetailsDTO> GetUserDetails(int userId)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> params = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    params.Add("@UserId",userId);

    return ExecuteProcedure<UserDetailsDTO>("spGetUserDetails", params);
}

Now with my new requirement where the data structure returned by the stored procedure varies based on the table name parameter being passed to it, I am not sure how I can have my DTOs be dynamic.
Any inputs or suggestions on this?

Can you use the Microsoft Entity Framework?
for .net Framework
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application
for .net core
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli
here an example with StoredProcedure:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29012920/entity-framework-return-list-from-stored-procedure

"i am passing table name as parameter to SQL Server stored procedure and that stored procedure returns the data from that table" such a set up is often a sign of an XY Problem.

@GustavoOliveira Currently the application is setup using ADO.NET

Relational databases are not designed/intended for generic/DRY code. They are designed for specific static code.

How is your application going to use the values once they come out? If you have different places in code that pass different hard-coded table parameters in, knowing what type of value to expect, then you can use a Generic type on your helper method. If the calling code just passes the values through to someplace else (e.g. to be serialized), you might just want to use a Dictionary.

@StriplingWarrior The table name will be passed from the front end based on dropdown value selection, Once the Data access layer returns the values, these vales will be returned to the business layer and from busines layer to the API controller and the API controller action method will return in the form of JSON array which will be used in the FE and display the resultset in a grid.

Why do you even need DTOs? Sounds like you just wanna get the JSON right away

I would recommend reading the returned rows out into something like a Dictionary<string, object> as described here.
List<Dictionary<string, object>> items = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
using (var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
{
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> obj = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                string columnName = reader.GetName(i);
                object columnValue = reader.GetValue(i);
                obj[columnName] = columnValue;
            }
            items.Add(obj);
        }
    }
}

Then just have your function return this list to be serialized.

You do it exactly the same way, with a fixed DTO for each database call, even if you have a single stored procedure that returns different resultsets (which is an annoying and useless pattern).  eg
public IList<UserDetailsDTO> GetUserDetails(int userId)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> params = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    params.Add("@Id",userId);
    params.Add("@EntityName","UserDetails");

    return ExecuteProcedure<UserDetailsDTO>("usp_GetWhatever", params);
}


"Which is an annoying and useless pattern" ✅

Do i need to have multiple methods in DAL with a fixed DTO for each parameter ?

You should.  But if you use reflection instead your computer won't catch on fire.  And if you don't have DTO types, you'll have to generate the JSON in code.  Again, something you could do, but I wouldn't.

I'm reading between the lines here and assuming that maybe the database schema isn't really coupled to the application domain, in which case it wouldn't be appropriate to have to change code to add DTOs every time a table is changed.
